# Lat / Lng to create a Marker on Google Map V3

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps, geolocation

I have my Lat and Lng in my database, when I try to combine them to create a Marker on a map, it doesn't work. Attributes data-lat and lng are from my html codes, which represent the real lat and lng from my database.

Lat :10.432548 and Lng : 32.4972830002 .

Really appreciate it if you look at my codes and help me to fix it . Thanks

```
    var marker;
    var Gmap = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas').get(0),mapOptions);
    var lat= $(this).attr('data-lat');
    var lng= $(this).attr('data-lng');
    var newLocation= lat+', '+lng;

    if(lat!=0 || lng!=0){

            if (marker) {
                marker.setPosition(newLocation);
            }else{
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: newLocation,
                    map: Gmap
                });
            }   

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I just fixed it ....

```
var newLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
```